# WebDriver python equivalent of "refreshed" expected condition

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So, using WebDriver python binding, I came across a problem that I need to wait until an element is refreshed on the page. Say, I have two `radio buttons`, and by clicking either of them, a `label` text is changed.

Currently, if I click on one and get the text and then click on the other and get the text again, I will get the same text although it has changed. Thus, I think I need to wait for the element to be refreshed.

On Java documentation, there is a [refreshed](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#refreshed-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition-) expected condition which appears to be useful in this case. But I'm unable to find the python version of it. What is its equivalent? How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text_to_be_present_in_element()` under `expected_conditions.py` is similar to what you're looking for. If it's not the `value` that's changing but instead another field like `textContent`, you could roll a custom solution which is similar to `text_to_be_present_in_element()`.

```
def attribute_text_is_in_element(text, locator, attribute):
    try:
        element_text = driver.find_element(locator).get_attribute(attribute)
        if text == element_text:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying my best to avoid sending the text as param to the function and instead have it at my test case side. But this actually works.

Comment: @notbertpy Take another look, `text_to_be_present_in_element()` was actually just checking if the text exists, not on if it is equal. New solution should work fine though.

Comment: I wanted to have `getter` on my page object to simply return the updated value. Then delegate the assertion to my test case. Whether it's equal, or a regex needs to be run, or any kind of string comparison must be inside my test case rather than on my page object.

Comment: @norbertpy You could modify this to be attribute_text_not_in_element(old_text, locator, attribute)', do wait.until(...), then have a getter` which returns driver.find_element(locator).get_attribute(attribute) after. Would that be better for you? You could dynamically grab the oldText from the label without having to hard code it in.